# Not able to boot micro-service using spring boot with swagger 2

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I'm trying to use swagger 2 with spring boot but i'm getting the following exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration]: Factory method 'security' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration.
```

My configuration class for swagger is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig{
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And i have added following 2 dependencies in my pom:

```
             <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: what version of spring boot?

Comment: Spring boot version is 1.2.5

Comment: that is an ancient and EOL'd version of spring boot. You should be on 1.5.X family which is still recieving updates at least. Otherwise you'lll likely need to downgrade swagger.

Comment: Thanks Darren.Which downgraded version of swagger should i use?

Comment: Spring boot 1.5.x or 2.x works fine with swagger 2.6

Comment: Thanks gaganbm. Able to boot service.